# Re-install MacOS (High Sierra) with terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, high-sierra, install, apfs

This may be a bit of an open-ended question:

I am would like to do an OS reinstall of High Sierra, but block it from converting the disk to the APFS format. This would necessitate the use of terminal with this section of command executed:

```
--converttoapfs NO
```

added after the file location of the High Sierra installer.

I have some software issues, and need to do a reinstall through the *command + R* boot procedure. I upgraded to 13.6 without converting to APFS and want to solve this issue and reinstall whilst keeping the disk HFS+ formatted. I have some technical knowledge, enough to fix most problems on my own, but this is something I would rather hash out with more guidance and advice.

Therefore, which is the best method of me doing this?

- Reinstall High Sierra normally with Finder and terminal?
- Reinstall in the MacOS UEFI using terminal?
- Some other method I haven't thought of/don't know of

Any responses and help would be much appreciated.

---

Thanks, Meriones.

Comment: "I have some software issues" ...wouldn't it be simpler to just tackle those, head-on?

Comment: From what I've found, not really. I have an issue with not being able to control screen brightness on my MBPr 2013. I was able to address the issue somewhat under Sierra, but I haven't found a solution for High Sierra.

Comment: When booted into Internet Recovery, use Disk Utility to set up your HFS+ partition. When you go through the install process, during the first step (selecting the partition to install to), there should be a checkbox that allows you to specify whether you want to convert the selected HFS+ partition to APFS.